# animation from Random Polygon to Ellipse

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote, animations

For an animation with TikZ and Asymptote (that I am somehow familiar with), its size is accumulative with the number of steps. I am mimicking animation for [From Random Polygon to Ellipse](https://www.jasondavies.com/random-polygon-ellipse/), take a polygon with random vertices, find the mid-points of its sides, and use these to create a new polygon, replacing the original. Do this repeatedly and an ellipse will eventually form. See [here](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/090746707) for more explanation.

[image]

In this situation, the number of steps/frames is large or extremely large, and only last step/frame is needed.

Can we do it with TikZ or Asymptote? Do you have any other recommendation?

PS: I can add a MWE with TikZ/Asymptote, but as said above, I think it is useless.

Comment: What is useless and why?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I thought that this animation can't be done with TikZ/Asymptote. It seems that I am wrong.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** Convergence detection to limit number of iterations and animation length

This solution implements the algorithm in section 1.3 of the [above-cited reference](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/090746707), which re-normalises the new polygon vertex coordinates to prevent the polygon from collapsing to a point.

Implementation is done in LaTeX3 and `l3fparray`s are used as containers for the polygon *x* and *y* coordinates. Plotting is done with Ti*k*z.

In converged state, polygon vertices jump forth and back between edge centres and the positions after the previous iteration. Hence, for testing convergence, a set of two consecutive iterations and a subsequent normalisation are carried out which then allows the change of vertex coordinates to be evaluated. This convergence test is carried out at the end of each animation frame.

---

*n*=50 polygon example; click to run **SVG** animation (**11.3 MiB**) in the browser:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}                    % lualatex
%\documentclass[dvisvgm,autoplay]{standalone} % dvilualatex + dvisvgm
%\documentclass[export]{standalone} % lualatex + imagemagick (PDF to animated GIF)

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\n{50}                   % #vertices
\def\animationStepsMax{10000}% hard limit of #animation frames
\def\iterationsPerFrame{2}   % #iterations per animation step; must be >= 2
\def\maxnorm{5.0e-5}         % max norm of vertex coordinate change vectors between iterations
% tikzpicture properties
\def\bboxLowerLeft{-0.4,-0.4}% bounding box coords
\def\bboxUpperRight{0.4,0.4}
\def\scalePicture{6}         % factor for scaling
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ExplSyntaxOn
% computes the edge centres; takes two fparrays of same length with polygon x and
% y coordinates and modifies them in place
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn\computeEdgeCentres#1#2{{
  \fp_set:Nn\l_tmpa_fp{\fparray_item:Nn#1{1}}
  \fp_set:Nn\l_tmpb_fp{\fparray_item:Nn#2{1}}
  \int_step_inline:nn{\fparray_count:N#1-1}{
    \fparray_gset:Nnn#1{##1}{(\fparray_item:Nn#1{##1}+\fparray_item:Nn#1{##1+1})/2}
    \fparray_gset:Nnn#2{##1}{(\fparray_item:Nn#2{##1}+\fparray_item:Nn#2{##1+1})/2}
  }
  \fparray_gset:Nnn#1{\fparray_count:N#1}{(\fparray_item:Nn#1{\fparray_count:N#1}+\l_tmpa_fp)/2}
  \fparray_gset:Nnn#2{\fparray_count:N#2}{(\fparray_item:Nn#2{\fparray_count:N#2}+\l_tmpb_fp)/2}
}}

% normalises polygon vertex coordinates in place;
% arguments: 2 fparrays of same length, each having unit 2-norm afterwards
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn\normalisePolygon#1#2{{
  \computeTwoNorm\l_tmpa_tl#1
  \computeTwoNorm\l_tmpb_tl#2
  \int_step_inline:nn{\fparray_count:N#1}{
    \fparray_gset:Nnn#1{##1}{\fparray_item:Nn#1{##1}/\l_tmpa_tl}
    \fparray_gset:Nnn#2{##1}{\fparray_item:Nn#2{##1}/\l_tmpb_tl}
  }
}}

% re-centres about (0,0) polygon coordinates (two fparrays)
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn\recentrePolygon#1#2{{
  \fp_zero:N\l_tmpa_fp
  \fp_zero:N\l_tmpb_fp
  \int_set:Nn\l_tmpa_int{\fparray_count:N#1}
  \int_step_inline:nn{\l_tmpa_int}{
    \fp_add:Nn\l_tmpa_fp{\fparray_item:Nn#1{##1}}
    \fp_add:Nn\l_tmpb_fp{\fparray_item:Nn#2{##1}}
  }
  \fp_set:Nn\l_tmpa_fp{\l_tmpa_fp/\l_tmpa_int}
  \fp_set:Nn\l_tmpb_fp{\l_tmpb_fp/\l_tmpa_int}
  \int_step_inline:nn{\n}{
    \fparray_gset:Nnn#1{##1}{\fparray_item:Nn#1{##1}-\l_tmpa_fp}
    \fparray_gset:Nnn#2{##1}{\fparray_item:Nn#2{##1}-\l_tmpb_fp}
  }
}}

% computes 2-norm of vector argument (arg #2, fparray) and places result
% in tl variable (arg #1)
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn\computeTwoNorm#1#2{
  \tl_set:Nn#1{0}
  \int_step_inline:nn{\fparray_count:N#2}{
    \tl_set:Nx#1{\fp_to_tl:n{#1+\fparray_item:Nn#2{##1}*\fparray_item:Nn#2{##1}}}
  }
  \tl_set:Nx#1{\fp_to_tl:n{sqrt(#1)}}
}

% sorts elements of fparray in place
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn\bubbleSort#1{{
  \int_set:Nn\l_tmpa_int{\fparray_count:N#1}
  \int_do_while:nn{\l_tmpb_int=\c_one_int}{
    \int_zero:N\l_tmpb_int
    \int_step_inline:nnn{1}{\l_tmpa_int-1}{
      \fp_compare:nT{\fparray_item:Nn#1{##1}>\fparray_item:Nn#1{##1+1}}{
        \fp_set:Nn\l_tmpa_fp{\fparray_item:Nn#1{##1}}
        \fparray_gset:Nnn#1{##1}{\fparray_item:Nn#1{##1+1}}
        \fparray_gset:Nnn#1{##1+1}{\l_tmpa_fp}
        \int_set_eq:NN\l_tmpb_int\c_one_int
      }
    }
    \int_decr:N\l_tmpa_int
  }
}}

% subtracts second from first fparray argument, changing the first in place
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn\subtractSecondFromFirst#1#2{
  \int_step_inline:nn{\fparray_count:N#1}{
    \fparray_gset:Nnn#1{##1}{\fparray_item:Nn#1{##1}-\fparray_item:Nn#2{##1}}
  }
}

% copies elements of second into elements of first fparray argument
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn\copySecondToFirst#1#2{
  \int_step_inline:nn{\fparray_count:N#1}{
    \fparray_gset:Nnn#1{##1}{\fparray_item:Nn#2{##1}}
  }
}

% returns polygon vertex coordinate out of two fparray arguments by index;
% arg  #1: vertex index (integer),
% arg  #2, #3: x and y fparrays with vertex coordinates
\cs_new_nopar:Npn\getVertexCoord#1#2#3{
  \fparray_item_to_tl:Nn#2{#1},\fparray_item_to_tl:Nn#3{#1}
}

\let\fpCompareTrue\fp_compare:nT % alias for use outside of ExplSyntax
\let\intStepInline\int_step_inline:nn

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% initialise starting random polygon
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% allocate fparrays for polygon x and y coordinates
\fparray_new:Nn\polyX{\n}
\fparray_new:Nn\polyY{\n}
% initialise coordinates with random values
\sys_gset_rand_seed:n{691422}
\int_step_inline:nn{\n}{
  \fparray_gset:Nnn\polyX{#1}{rand()}
  \fparray_gset:Nnn\polyY{#1}{rand()}
}
% centre polygon around (0,0)
\recentrePolygon\polyX\polyY
% normalise polygon coordinates
\normalisePolygon\polyX\polyY
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\fparray_new:Nn\polyXCurr{\n} % for convergence test
\fparray_new:Nn\polyYCurr{\n}
\fparray_new:Nn\polyXPrev{\n}
\fparray_new:Nn\polyYPrev{\n}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\gdef\isConverged{0}%
\begin{animateinline}[controls]{25}
  \multiframe{\inteval{\animationStepsMax+1}}{i=0+\iterationsPerFrame}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\scalePicture]
      \useasboundingbox (\bboxLowerLeft) rectangle (\bboxUpperRight);
      \draw[line join=bevel,every node/.style={circle,draw,fill=white,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=2pt}]
        (\getVertexCoord{1}\polyX\polyY) node {}
        foreach \i in {2,...,\inteval{\n}} {--(\getVertexCoord{\i}\polyX\polyY) node {}} --cycle;
      \node [anchor=south west] at (current bounding box.south west) {Step \i};
      \node [label={[inner sep=0pt]left:\scriptsize O},inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\tiny$\times$};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \ifnum\isConverged>0\multiframebreak\fi% stop frame generation if converged
    % core algorithm
    \intStepInline{\iterationsPerFrame-2}{%
      \computeEdgeCentres\polyX\polyY% new polygon vertices on edge centres
      \ifnum\inteval{\iterationsPerFrame-2}=#1
        \normalisePolygon\polyX\polyY% after last iteration, normalise new coordinates
      \fi%
    }%
    % convergence testing
    \copySecondToFirst\polyXPrev\polyX%
    \copySecondToFirst\polyYPrev\polyY%
    \computeEdgeCentres\polyX\polyY% two more iterations
    \computeEdgeCentres\polyX\polyY%
    \normalisePolygon\polyX\polyY% ... and normalisation
    \copySecondToFirst\polyXCurr\polyX%
    \copySecondToFirst\polyYCurr\polyY%
    \bubbleSort\polyXPrev%
    \bubbleSort\polyYPrev%
    \bubbleSort\polyXCurr%
    \bubbleSort\polyYCurr%
    \subtractSecondFromFirst\polyXPrev\polyXCurr%
    \subtractSecondFromFirst\polyYPrev\polyYCurr%
    \computeTwoNorm\tmpa\polyXPrev%
    \computeTwoNorm\tmpb\polyYPrev%
    \typeout{coord change vectors: ||dx||=\tmpa, ||dy||=\tmpb}%
    \fpCompareTrue{\tmpa<\maxnorm && \tmpb<\maxnorm}{\gdef\isConverged{1}}
  }
\end{animateinline}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is asymptote code.  Note that the polygon shrinks as it iterates toward the ellipse.  You can uncomment the 5 commented lines to scale up the path size as the iterations progress if you wish.

I compile this code with `asy solution -noV -f pdf` to create a multipage PDF file.  Set your PDF viewer to view a single page, then you can "animate" by using "Page Down" on your keyboard.

```
unitsize(1inch);

int numPoints = 20;
int numIterations = 100;

path updateToMidpoints(path pin)
{
    path p;
    for (int i = 0; i < length(pin); ++i)
    {
        p = p--(0.5*(point(pin, i) + point(pin, i+1)));
    }

    real scaleFactor = 1.0;

    // pair startingDimensions = max(pin) - min(pin);
    // pair endingDimensions = max(p) - min(p);
    // real xscale = startingDimensions.x / endingDimensions.x;
    // real yscale = startingDimensions.y / endingDimensions.y;
    // real scaleFactor = xscale < yscale ? xscale : yscale;

    p = scale(scaleFactor)*(p--cycle); // scale

    return p;
}

path p = (unitrand(), unitrand());
for (int i = 1; i < numPoints; ++i) { p = p--(unitrand(), unitrand()); }
p = scale(3)*shift(-0.5,-0.5)*(p--cycle);

for (int i = 0; i < numIterations; ++i)
{
    draw(p);
    dot(p, 3+red);
    dot((0,0), 3+black);
    newpage();
    p = updateToMidpoints(p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that PGF/TikZ doesn't care whether a referenced coordinate/node is actually in another picture (unless `remember picture` is set) we can simply loop through all vertices and place new ones at the midway point between them. Each vertex exists twice because we can't simply overwrite them since each vertex is also used twice to calculate a new position.

The `only every = k` can be used to show only every *k*th diagram. This is very simply implemented and needs to an even number (due to the swappingof suffixes). The part that only calculates the midway points is down in PGF and also uses one instance of a `\pgfmathloop` that should be faster than the full `\foreach` construct. (All these `\foreach` loops are pretty simple actually.)

The macro `\tikzrptedo` simply outputs every *k*th diagram, including the 0th one that places the first instances of the vertices.

The various styles allow us to change the visualization depending on the number of the diagram or the step or …

Further optimization for less flexibility are possible. (And instead of nodes, plotmarks could be used.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, graphs}
\newcommand*\tikzrpteset{\pgfqkeys{/tikz/rpte}}% Random Polygon To Ellipse = rpte
\tikzrpteset{
  n/.initial=10,
  steps/.initial=10,
  @vertex/.style={draw, shape=circle, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+.5mm},
  vertex/.style=rpte/@vertex,
  edge/.style=draw,
  only every/.initial=1,
  every diagram/.style={
    x=+5cm, y=+5cm,
    execute at begin picture={% consistent bounding box
      \node foreach \p in {(0,0), (1,1)} [rpte/@vertex, path only] at \p {};}}}
\newcommand*\tikzrpteswap{\let\temp\rpteSuffixA\global\let\rpteSuffixA\rpteSuffixB\global\let\rpteSuffixB\temp}
\newcommand*\tikzrptedo[1][]{%
  \begingroup
  \tikzrpteset{#1}%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\rpteN{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rpte/n}}%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\rpteEvery{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rpte/only every}}%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\rpteSteps{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/rpte/steps}}%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\rpteEach{\rpteSteps/\rpteEvery}%
  \gdef\rpteSuffixA{'}\gdef\rpteSuffixB{}%
  \def\rpteStep{0}\def\rpteDiagram{0}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    rpte/every diagram,
    rpte/diagram \rpteDiagram/.try,
    rpte/step \rpteStep/.try]
  \node foreach \rpteEach in {1, ..., \rpteN}
    [rpte/vertex, rpte/vertex \rpteEach/.try] at (rnd, rnd) (rpteV\rpteEach) {};
  \pgfnodealias{rpteV0}{rpteV\rpteN};
  \graph[use existing nodes, cycle, edges=rpte/edge]{
    \foreach\rpteEach in {1, ..., \rpteN}{rpteV\rpteEach}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \foreach \rpteDiagram in {1, ..., \rpteEach}{%
    \edef\rpteStep{\pgfinteval{\rpteDiagram*\rpteEvery}}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      rpte/every diagram,
      rpte/diagram \rpteDiagram/.try,
      rpte/step \rpteStep/.try]
    \foreach\rpteIter in {1, ..., \pgfinteval{\rpteEvery-1}}{
      \pgfmathloop
        \pgfcoordinate
          {rpteV\pgfmathcounter\rpteSuffixA}
          {\pgfpointlineattime{.5}
            {\pgfpointanchor{rpteV\pgfinteval{\pgfmathcounter-1}\rpteSuffixB}{center}}
            {\pgfpointanchor{rpteV\pgfmathcounter\rpteSuffixB}{center}}}%
        \ifnum\pgfmathcounter<\rpteN
      \repeatpgfmathloop
      \pgfnodealias{rpteV0\rpteSuffixA}{rpteV\rpteN\rpteSuffixA}%
      \tikzrpteswap
    }
    \node foreach \rpteIter in {1, ..., \rpteN}
      [rpte/vertex, rpte/vertex \rpteIter/.try,
       at={($(rpteV\pgfinteval{\rpteIter-1}')!.5!(rpteV\rpteIter')$)},
       name=rpteV\rpteIter] {};
    \pgfnodealias{rpteV0}{rpteV\rpteN}
    \graph[use existing nodes, cycle, edges=rpte/edge]{\foreach\rpteIter in {1, ..., \rpteN}{rpteV\rpteIter}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
  \endgroup}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetseed{691422}
\tikzrptedo
\pgfmathsetseed{691422}
\tikzrptedo[
  steps=1000, n=50, only every=20,
  vertex/.append code={\ifnum\rpteStep>200 \tikzset{shape=coordinate}\fi},
  every diagram/.append style={
    execute at end picture={
      \node[above right] {Step: \rpteStep};}}]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: There is a scaling by normalizing at each step/frame.